# How can I remove the border from one column of an HtmlTable AND the part of the encompassing table that touches it?

Tags: html, css, border, html-table

I need to remove the border lines from the last column of an htmltable. I tried this on the last "column" (td) of the table:

```
<td class="nobordercell">Comments</td>

.nobordercell {
  border: none;
}
```

I also tried this (border-collapse: collapse):

```
<table class="middletable" border="1">
    <tr>
        . . .
        <td name="airfaredate1Comments" id="airfaredate1Comments" class="nobordercell">Comments</td>
    </tr>
    . . .

.middletable{
    width:99%;
    float:left;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

The only edge of the border that disappears is the bottom. I realize that this is because the still-showing borders belong to the table, not the td, but still need to know how I can remove the border from the htmltable ONLY on the parts where the td's border and it intersect (or *would* intersect, if the td's borders were displaying).

This is how it looks currently:

[image]

...and this is how I want it to look:

[image]

Comment: it looks like your `table` or `tr` itself having border

Comment: You have a border of 1 defined in your table. `<table class="middletable" border="1">`, changing it to 0 should remove the border from the table.

Comment: I want the border on the table in general; just not on the "column"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :last-child selector:

```
table tr td:last-child {
border: none;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp

Answer (score 1):

Some simple css and arranging should help do the trick, included a JSFiddle. Also, had to remove the border from your HTML table tag:

```
.middletable{
    width:99%;
    float:left;
    border:none;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.bordercell{
    border:1px solid black;
}

.nobordercell {
  border: none;
}

<table class="middletable">
    <tr>
        <td name="airfaredate1Comments" id="airfaredate1Comments" class="bordercell">Comments</td>
                <td class="nobordercell">Comments</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>

        <td name="airfaredate1Comments" id="airfaredate1Comments" class="bordercell">Comments</td>
                    <td class="nobordercell">Comments</td>
    </tr>

        <tr>
        <td name="airfaredate1Comments" id="airfaredate1Comments" class="bordercell">Comments</td>
                    <td class="nobordercell">Comments</td>
    </tr>


</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0v9vdd58/

Answer (score 1):

You could use the CSS3 `:last-of-type` selector.

```
.middletable{
    width:99%;
    float:left;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.middletable td{
  border:1px solid black;
}

.middletable td:last-of-type{
    border:0px;
}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<table class="middletable">
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

And here's a JSFiddle to demonstrate the code in action: http://jsfiddle.net/5pt2axd1/